# Media Query for JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm attempting to set a media query for this script with no luck. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
<script>

var mq = window.matchMedia( "(min-width: 1024px)" );

if (mq.matches) {
   $(".number-<?php echo $counter; ?>").hover(function () {
     $(".section-<?php echo $section; ?> #hover-button-<?php echo $counter; ?>").stop().slideToggle();
     return false;
 });
}
else {

}
 </script>
```

Comment: What's not working? What is expected behavior? Take a few minutes to read through [ask] and [mcve] then edit question with  fully detailed problem description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `onchange` event of `matchMedia`

```js
var mq = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 1024px)");

function mediaChange() {
  console.log(mq.matches)
  
  if (mq.matches) {
    $(".number-1").hover(function() {
      $(".section-1 #hover-button-1").stop().slideToggle();
      return false;
    });
  } else {
    $(".number-1").off('mouseenter mouseleave')
  }
  
}
mediaChange();

mq.onchange = mediaChange;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="number-1">
  hover me
</div>

<div class="section-1">
  <div id="hover-button-1">
    toggle
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** View the demo in `Full Page` mode (right of Run button)

Comment: Makes far more sense to check the match inside event handler

Comment: @charlietfl Good catch

Answer (score 0):

It seems this works using max-width rather than min-width

```
<script>

var mq = window.matchMedia( "(max-width: 1024px)" );

if (mq.matches) {

}

else {

   $(".number-<?php echo $counter; ?>").hover(function () {
     $(".section-<?php echo $section; ?> #hover-button-<?php echo $counter; ?>").stop().slideToggle();
     return false;
    });

}
 </script>
```